# Uploading text file in server using django

Tags: django, file

I have a created a website which allows users to login by giving user name and password..Now i want to make an option which will allow the file from local machine to upload to a server.How can i do this?

Comment: I think you can google it easily, I google it and find this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/ , hope helps

Answer (score 0):

Follow documentation on [File Uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/)